# Firebase download huge dataset android

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying download dataset from firebase after login. About 23 000 records for some counting and offline capabilities.
It takes a lot of time, processor time and memory.

When I tried pagination for taking 500 records at the time it take a lot of cpu time, almost 45% for 10 minutes. It's such a battery drainer.

I have to use firebase for realtime capabilities.

Does anyone experience with this case or any idea how to do this initial download more effectively?

It took a screenshot for better understanding

[image]

Blue is memory, red CPU and orange is network.

Thank you for any help.

**EDIT:**

Pagination is solving only memory issue (when I downloading data, app is not taking abou 120 MB ram on my phone). Problem is that I can download 500 record almost immediately and when I downloading one page in 23k records it takes almost 10 seconds...

Data looks like:

[image]

**EDIT2:**
I maybe figured out the fastest way. I'm using firebase REST API for download this amount of data and it's faster and better (for my purpose) than getting data from SDK.

For caching in firebase storage on phone I use this code

```
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = getReference(db);
db.goOffline();
ref.updateChildren(mapFromResponse);
db.goOnline();
```

Comment: The time it takes to download data is mostly depended on the size of that data and the bandwidth of the device where you are downloading. But it's hard to say anything more useful without seeing a [minimal reproduction of the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: +1 to what Puf said. But can your users really view 500 records at a time? I can't view 500 of anything. So maybe that's more data than you should bother with?

Comment: Thanks for responses... Kato: User cannot view 500 records at the time, I download it only for caching in phone. I have to able to see data offline. I described problem more in main post.

Answer (score 2):

In my app, **I also need to download a lot of data records** from Firebase when the app launches for the first time and them they are cached offline.

Yes, it takes some time to download them initially, but there is very little you can do. If there are lots of data, then it will take some time. Even if you try to take the pagination approach, still you have to download those data anyhow.

You can show a indeterminate loading to the user while downloading this data and make sure **they are cached locally in Firebase** so that they are not downloaded again.

Comment: Thanks for response.  I described problem in main post